# On a proof of Riesz-Thorin with the tensor power trick

Tags: lp-spaces, interpolation-theory

In [this post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/tricks-wiki-article-the-tensor-product-trick/) Terence Tao exposes the tensor power trick, and leaves as an exercise to use this tecnique to prove Riesz-Thorin. This is what I managed to do (I will use the same notation as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249392/intuition-behind-the-riesz-thorin-interpolation-theorem)):

First, note that
$$ ||T||_{p_\vartheta\to q_\vartheta}\le ||T||_{p_0\to q_0}^{1-\vartheta}||T||_{p_1\to q_1}^\vartheta$$
holds for $T$ iff it holds for $cT$. Similarly, it holds for $\mu_2$ iff it holds for $k\mu_2$. Rescaling these two, we can suppose $||T||_{p_0\to q_0}=1=||T||_{p_1\to q_1}$. So we have to prove that $||T||_{p_\vartheta\to q_\vartheta}\le 1$.
This is where I get stuck: the idea is to prove that, for $f\in L^{p_0}\cap L^{p_1}$, we have
$$\int_{\Omega_2} |Tf|^{q_\vartheta}\le C\|f\|_{p_\vartheta}$$
From this, the tensor power trick implies easily that the ineuqlity still holds for $C=1$ and the result for general $f$ is obtained as in the usual proof of Riesz-Thorin (see e.g. Folland).
I do not know how to prove that inequality. My first idea was to do something like
$$\int_{\Omega_2}|Tf|^{q_\vartheta}\le \int_{\Omega_2}|Tf|^{q_0}+|Tf|^{q_1}\le ||f||_{p_0}^{q_0}+||f||_{p_1}^{q_1}$$
but this does not seem to lead anywhere.

I would appreciate either hints on how to continue this proof or on how to approach the problem in some different way (using the tensor power trick, I already know the proof with the $3$ lines lemma).

Comment: I think the idea is to use the first part of the proof for space $\Omega_2$ being product of n spaces $\Omega_2 {x}\Omega_2 {x}...$ and $f(x_1,x_2,..) = f(x_1)*f(x_2)*...$. Then, using Fubini theorem you get that the left side to $n$ power is not bigger than $C$ times the right side to $n-th$. Taking $n$ root from both sides gives you constant $C^{\frac{1}{n}}$, for any $n$. Hence, the best constant is $1$.

Comment: this was an interesting read, and I'm also curious to find the answer (I tried for a little bit then gave up :) My attempt was to mimic the proof of the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem to establish the desired inequality (with some prefactors, which we can then eliminate using the Tensor power trick). Though I wonder if it is possible to do so by more elementary means by mimicking the example (on Hausdorff-Young) which precedes this question.

Comment: One possibility is to use the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem, but this requires $p_\theta \le q_\theta$, see also Exercises 33 and 34 in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/#more-1977. However, there is one thing that is confusing me: This proof by the tensor trick method should work in this case $p_\theta \le q_\theta$ and (since no complex analysis is involved) should give the Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem in the real case with constant $1$. But there is a counterexample (https://doi.org/10.1007/s000130050241) that this is not possible.

Comment: ... only under assumption $p_\theta \le q_\theta$ ($p_0 \le q_0$ and $p_1 \le q_1$ seem to be needed).