# Jensen's gap & expectation & limit

Tags: probability

Let we have a random variable $a$ and we know the expectation of it.
Then, I think we can have $\mathbb{E}[a^{(1+\delta)}]\ge\mathbb{E}[a]^{(1+\delta)}$. The equality holds for $\delta = 0$.

In this case, can we say that
there exists a small enough $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that $\mathbb{E}[a^{(1+\delta)}] \le \mathbb{E}[a]^{(1+\delta)}+\epsilon$ for all $\delta < \delta_\epsilon$?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: No. For example $f(x) = C (1+x^2)^{-1} (1+\ln(1+x))^{-2}$ for $x>0$, say. (Assume it is a positive random variable to make sense of fractional powers without absolute values.) Then $\int_{0}^{\infty} x f(x)\, dx<\infty$ but $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{1+\delta} f(x)\, dx=\infty$ for all $\delta>0$.

Comment: @ShannonStarr Thank you so much! I have one more question. Then, is there any way to have upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[a^{(1+\delta)}]$? or we cannot have any finite upper bound for it?

Comment: Let $a$ be a positive random variable. If there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $\mathbb{E}[a^{(1+\delta_1)}]<\infty$ then for $\delta \in [0,\delta_1]$ you can use H\"older's inequality on $\mathbb{E}[a^{1+\delta}]=\mathbb{E}[a^{(1+\delta)\theta} a^{(1+\delta)(1-\theta)}]$ with $p=1/((1+\delta)\theta)$, $q=1/(1-(1/p))$ and $\theta = (\delta_1-\delta)/((1+\delta) \delta_1$ to get an upper bound of $\mathbb{E}[a]^{(\delta_1-\delta)/\delta_1} \mathbb{E}[a^{1+\delta_1}]^{\delta/\delta_1}$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249392/intuition-behind-the-riesz-thorin-interpolation-theorem

Comment: @ShannonStarr Thank you so much!